# Document Merger using PhpDocX

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, ms-word, phpdocx

I'm developing a document merger that utilizes an FTP site containing hundreds of documents.

**FTP Connection Function**

```
private static function establishFTP() {
    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect(getenv('FTP_HOST'));
    ftp_login($ftp_conn,getenv('FTP_USER'),getenv('FTP_PASS'));
    ftp_pasv($ftp_conn,true);

    return $ftp_conn;
}
```

I have a function that connects to the FTP site and generates an array of the documents stored inside a designated directory. It will remove the extensions from any files that are of type `.docx`. Then it will filter out all values containing a `.`. This removes any extra files that are not a Word document and also removes the FTP root pathings of `.` and `..` from the array.

**Form Generation Function**

```
public static function generateForm() {
    $ftp_conn = self::establishFTP();

    $forms = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn,getenv('FTP_DIRECTORY'));
    $forms = str_replace('.docx','',$forms);
    $forms = array_filter($forms,function($value) {
        return strpos($value,'.') === false;
    });

    ftp_close($ftp_conn);

    return view('testDoc')->with(array('forms'=>$forms));
}
```

My view is very basic right now just to prove functionality. There is lots of design work that needs done to make it more user-friendly and functional.

**Blade View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<title>Form</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{ Form::open(array('action'=>'DocumentController@mergeDocument')) }}
@foreach($forms as $doc)
    {{ Form::checkbox('documents[]',$doc) }}
    {{ Form::label(null,$doc) }}
@endforeach
{{ Form::submit('Submit',array('id'=>'submitBtn')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly, I have a function that will accept an array of string values from the GUI. It will then establish a FTP connection and grab all documents requested from the FTP site. It will store these in a temp directory until the documents are merged and downloaded to the browser. Then it will unlink all temp files.

**Merge and Download Documents Function**

```
public static function mergeDocument() {
    $ftp_conn = self::establishFTP();

    $forms = Input::get('documents');
    $mergeDocs = array();
    $mergeName = uniqid('temp/files/merge-') . '.docx';
    $documentName = 'policies_' . date('m-d-H-i-s');

    foreach($forms as $doc) {
        ftp_get($ftp_conn,"temp/files/$doc.docx",getenv('FTP_DIRECTORY') . "/$doc.docx",FTP_BINARY);
        $mergeDocs[] = "temp/files/$doc.docx";
    }

    $firstDoc = array_shift($mergeDocs);

    ftp_close($ftp_conn);

    $mergeResult = new \Phpdocx\Utilities\MultiMerge();
    $mergeResult->mergeDocx($firstDoc,$mergeDocs,$mergeName,array('enforceSectionPageBreak'=>true));

    $phpdocx = new \Phpdocx\Create\CreateDocxFromTemplate($mergeName);
    $phpdocx->createDocxAndDownload($documentName);

    foreach($forms as $doc) {
        unlink("temp/files/$doc.docx");
    }
    unlink($mergeName);
    unlink("$documentName.docx");
}
```

Any suggestions as to the security and design of my app is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Security: Credentials in ENV**

It is less than ideal to store your credentials in environment variables, as they may easily leak.

`phpinfo` for example will print all environment variables.

Of course, you don't want to allow access to phpinfo to just anyone either, but it may still leak, and not everyone who should be allowed to see phpinfo should be allowed to see the FTP credentials.

**Security: Directory Traversal which may lead to Information Leak and Limited DOS**

An attacker can delete arbitrary .docx files in arbitrary locations because you never check the input for directory traversal. The problematic code is this:

```
$forms = Input::get('documents');
[...]
foreach($forms as $doc) {
    unlink("temp/files/$doc.docx");
}
```

The impact of this is rather small, but depending on what you store on your server, there may be some damage from this.

As you actually know what files are acceptable, you can easily use a whitelist approach here. At a minimum, you should check if the normalized path is inside the root dir.

Alternatively, if you do decide to cache filenames locally (see below), you could simply pass ids to the user instead of filenames, avoiding the problem altogether.

The same problem also exists here:

```
$forms = Input::get('documents');
[...]
foreach($forms as $doc) {
    ftp_get($ftp_conn,"temp/files/$doc.docx",getenv('FTP_DIRECTORY') . "/$doc.docx",FTP_BINARY);
    $mergeDocs[] = "temp/files/$doc.docx";
}
```

An attacker could read .doxc files outside of the `FTP_DIRECTORY` (if the FTP server allows this, and if the local server is writable at the given directory, both rather big ifs, but I would still protect against this).

**Security: SSL**

Your FTP connection will not be encrypted, meaning that a theoretical man in the middle can intercept your FTP credentials or the transfered files.

This may or may not be a problem for your use-case.

An alternative would be [ftp_ssl_connect](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) or using [sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689540/how-to-sftp-with-php) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172289/connection-to-secure-ftp-server-from-php)).

**Security/Funktionality: DOS & Performance**

From what I can tell, each time I visit the website containing the form that lists files I can join, you open an FTP connection and  retrieve a list of all the files (which may be quite a lot).

A user (or multiple user) may accidentally or on purpose reload the form a bunch of times, causing performance problems.

I would definitely profile this and see what strain it puts on your server. It may make sense to cache the list of docs locally (if it doesn't change that often).

**Usability / Bug / Security: File Listing**

Your mechanism will hide all files which contain a dot in their filename, which may lead to hard to trace bugs.

Your current mechanism may also have security implications, as files with no extension (for example `secret`) are listed as well, even though they shouldn't be.

Instead, I would probably use an approach such as this:

- Filter out all files that do not have the docx extension
- Remove the .docx extension

**Naming**

You use `forms` in multiple places as variable name where it doesn't really make sense. The variable doesn't contain multiple forms, but actually multiple document names. This naming also leads to the odd to read `foreach($forms as $doc)` loop. Instead, you should name name these variables `$docs` (in `mergeDocument`, `generateForm`, and in the view).

Comment: I would love to use SSL for my FTP connection and have been trying to push SFTP to the client who then has to push their hosting provider to fix the bugs with their SFTP implementation. However, for the time being, No Encryption FTP is the only option we have right now.

Comment: You suggest to NOT use the .env file for storing credentials as there are small chances of data leaks. Do you have any preferable practices that you would suggest? Only other implementation I can think of is creating a credentials directory one level above root and adding a .ini file into that. That being said, if someone is getting credentials from my .env, then they should be able to get these credentials as well.

Comment: @Trojan404 Yes, storing the credentials in a file outside the webroot would be a good solution (could be an .ini, but .php would be fine as well). Both would be a lot better than ENV, because a call to phpinfo can happen quickly - eg someone uploads a "temporary" info.php file and forgets to delete it -, and getting phpinfo isn't in itself considered a critical vulnerability (which it would be at the moment), so it may not get fixed. This is actually a nice example for two security issues which for themselves do not cause any real harm, but put together, may be rather critical.